# how convert a 2 digit decimal to byte with same digits?

Tags: java, android, hex, byte

I am working with hex and byte numbers and now face with a problem at converting a thing as bellow:

```
int i= 26;
byte b = 0x00;
```

I want to have :

`b = 0x26;` ( 0x26 must be in format "byte")

or for example for

```
i= 90;
```

i must have

```
Byte b = 0x90;
```

Can you give me a method which does my work?
Thank u...

Comment: conversion of 4 byte data to 1 byte data?

Comment: No! just thing i said in question...

Comment: input is a decimal number (or an integer) with 2 digit,,, and out put is a byte with same digit...

Comment: Why do you want same number in byte that too appended with 0x which is what we use for hex numbers?

Comment: do you means is not need to putting 0x in first of 26?

Comment: depends on what exactly you need.. so what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: because i have a desfire card and i want writing to it. It has a command which data must be write one byte one byte to the card. And I want write a number like 5000. I want write to the card at this way :0x50 and 0x00.

Comment: So why not two String then?

Comment: because data for write must be one byte one byte. Or if i have 123456 i must write at this way : 0x12 0x34 0x56

Comment: -1! use google for this kind of questions. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+decimal+to+byte+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Byte.parseByte(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte-java.lang.String-int-) method to simply parse your "26" into a hex value used to create a `byte` primitive:

```
int number = 26;
String intString = Integer.toString(number);
byte b = Byte.parseByte(intString, 16);
```

The radix value of `16` is used because you want the byte to have a value which is equal to `0x26` and the `0x` prefix means hexadecimal which is base 16.

If you want a `Byte` object you can use [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-int-) instead:

```
Byte b = Byte.valueOf(intString, 16);
```

Comment: Could "0x" add by this method to the first of 26?

Comment: You can't call `parseByte("0x26", 16)` because the `String` can only contain digits from the given radix. For radix 16 that means 0-9 and A-F. The "0x" to indicate hex is not necessary because the radix of 16 specifies this.

Comment: I dont want saving number in format int to byte b , for example 26 , by 1A value, Instead I want saving by 0x26 value...Is it possible with your code?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The above code will take an `int` with value 26 and produce a `byte` which has the same value you would get by calling `byte b = 0x26`.